# sonarqube support for angular 2(typescript)

Tags: angularjs, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Since a long time, I am using sonarqube and sonar-scanner for code quality in Java project.
Now I am working in Angular 2(typeScript.
How can I integrate sonarqube with Angular project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's currently in the works. You can follow the development of the SonarTS analyzer here : https://github.com/SonarSource/SonarTS/issues

Answer (score 0):

Its easy to install sonarQube with Angular 4/5/7. Please check [this](http://musttoknow.com/setup-sonar-sonarqube-sonarts-angular-4-5-7/) blog. I found it good, simple steps, covered issues which are coming while setup. URL: http://musttoknow.com/setup-sonar-sonarqube-sonarts-angular-4-5-7/